# Android HttpClient crashes on execute request as AsyncTask

Tags: android, http, asynchronous

I'm trying to execute request and return response as async task.
but unfortunately it crashed without catching exception :(
Here's the code. Class that invokes async:

```
public class HttpUtilz{

HttpGet getRequest;

public NodeList executeGetAndReceiveNodeList(String url, String xpath)throws XPathExpressionException,IOException,ParserConfigurationException,SAXException{
    getRequest=new HttpGet(url);
    HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) new RetrieveAsyncResp().execute(getRequest);
    InputStream inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
    DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = builder.parse(inputStream);
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
    XPathFactory xPathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath xPath=xPathFactory.newXPath();
    XPathExpression xPathExpression = xPath.compile(xpath);
    return (NodeList)xPathExpression.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
}
```

}

Implementation of async:

```
public class RetrieveAsyncResp extends AsyncTask<HttpGet, String, HttpResponse> {

@Override
protected void onPreExecute(){
    super.onPreExecute();
}


@Override
protected HttpResponse doInBackground(HttpGet... get) {
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response;
    try {
        response = client.execute(get[0]);
    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        response=null;
    }
    return response;
}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(HttpResponse response){
    super.onPostExecute(response);
}
```

}

I'm passing the next in test:
String url = "http://new-rutor.org/search/batman%20v%20superman"; 
String xpath = "//div[@id='index']/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/a[2]";

The only thing emulator provides me is:

```
04-07 15:49:21.796    8396-8396/torrentz.com.torrentforme D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
04-07 15:49:33.016    8396-8396/torrentz.com.torrentforme D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
04-07 15:49:33.016    8396-8396/torrentz.com.torrentforme W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4d6eb20)
```

I'd appreciate any help/suggestions

Comment: add crash reports.

Comment: Stop using AsyncTask's they are just a world of pain.

Comment: @RohitArya I'd love to do so but using Bluestacks emulator provides me with this: 04-07 15:49:21.796    8396-8396/torrentz.com.torrentforme D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
04-07 15:49:33.016    8396-8396/torrentz.com.torrentforme D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
04-07 15:49:33.016    8396-8396/torrentz.com.torrentforme W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4d6eb20)

Comment: @Bootstrapper I can't as I need lot of requests performing at the same time within a threadpool

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to get read `response` right after scheduling async task.

```
HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) new RetrieveAsyncResp().execute(getRequest); // task being ca
InputStream inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
```

Async task work on a background thread, so right after calling `execute`, control moves to next line and by that time you will not have got your response.

Try to move the code of parsing `response` in `onPostExecute` of `async task`.

Also I don't know **how does this even work**:

```
HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) new RetrieveAsyncResp().execute(getRequest);
```

Your IDE would be showing `incompatible types` error.

Comment: Also, `execute()` returns the asynctask itself so there will be a `ClassCastException` trying to cast it to `HttpResponse`.